# How can I search my entire drive for a file without getting recursively stuck in /Volumes?

Tags: search

I'm looking for a txt file that contains a word.  However when I search my hard drive (or my TimeCapsule backup) I always get stuck in a recursive search of /Volumes/Hard Drive (etc).

The hardlink (or softlink, not sure) is causing me to never complete the search.

How can I search the entire harddrive (or backup drive) for a file without getting stuck in recursion?

Comment: How are you searching for it? Spotlight doesn't get confused by this, and `find` doesn't follow symlinks (although it will traverse other volumes unless you specify the `-x` option)...

Comment: Spotlight won't show results for the entire drive.

Comment: @jaume: It does if you explicitly tell it to include [system files](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4355) and [invisible files](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH11165) in the results.

Comment: @GordonDavisson: 
Thank you, I didn't know that, I always use `locate` in Terminal when doing a system wide search. In my comment above I was thinking of Spotlight as the search field that appears when you press Space+Command, not as the search function in Finder...

Answer (score 4):

Use `locate`, `grep` or `find` at the command line.

Open Applications>Utilities>Terminal and either use:

1. `sudo locate -0 '*.txt' | xargs -0 grep WORD 2>/dev/null`

   Substitute WORD with the word you want to search for. This is by far the **fastest** method.

   I'd recommend to recreate the locate database first to improve accuracy:

   `sudo /usr/libexec/locate.updatedb`

   Note that on OS X, the `locate` database is created by user `nobody`. That means that files hidden to `nobody` won't be indexed. You can modify `/usr/libexec/locate.updatedb` and comment out (that is, prefix with `#`) this section:

   ```
   if [ "$(id -u)" = "0" ]; then
        rc=0
        # 2013-03-08 jaume Correct mktemp
        export FCODES=`mktemp --tmpdir updatedbXXXX`
        chown nobody $FCODES
        tmpdb=`su -fm nobody -c "$0"` || rc=1
        if [ $rc = 0 ]; then
            install -m 0444 -o nobody -g wheel $FCODES /var/db/locate.database
        fi
        rm $FCODES
        exit $rc
    fi
   ```

   so that it is indexed under user `root` (this applies to OS X 10.8 (Mountain Lion), on other OS X versions `locate` may index files differently).
2. `sudo grep -R --exclude-dir '/Volumes/<OS volume>' --exclude-dir '/Volumes/MobileBackups' --exclude-dir '/.Spotlight*' --exclude-dir '/.MobileBackups' --exclude-dir '/.DocumentRevisions*' --include '*.txt' WORD / 2>/dev/null`

   Substitute WORD with the word you want to search for and `<OS volume>` with the name of your OS volume. The `grep` options used are:

   - `-R`: does a recursive search in the specified path, that is, in `/`. If you search your TimeCapsule backup, replace `/` with something like `/Volumes/TimeCapsule`.
   - `--exclude-dir`: excludes the specified folders. As you see, I exclude Spotlight, the Versions folder and local TimeMachine folders. If you want to search your local drive only while your TimeCapsule is mounted, add `--exclude-dir /Volumes/TimeCapsule`.
   - `--include '*.txt'`: tells `grep` to search files which match `*.txt`.

   Additionally:

   - `2>/dev/null`: sends errors to `/dev/null` so that you don't see them.
3. `sudo find / ! -path '/.Spotlight*' ! -path '/Volumes/<OS volume>/*' ! -path '/Volumes/MobileBackups/*' ! -path '/.MobileBackups/*' ! -path '/.DocumentRevisions*' -name *.txt -type f -exec grep -H WORD {} + 2>/dev/null`

   Again, substitute WORD with the word you want to search for and `<OS volume>` with the name of your OS volume. As before, `2>/dev/null` sends errors to `/dev/null` so that you don't see them, and if you search your TimeCapsule backup, replace `/` with something like `/Volumes/TimeCapsule`.

   The `find` options used are:

   - `! -path`: exclude paths specified. If you want to search your local drive only while your TimeCapsule is mounted, add `! -path /Volumes/TimeCapsule/*`.
   - `-name *.txt`: search files named *.txt. As you see, I exclude Spotlight, the Versions folder and local TimeMachine folders.
   - `-type f`: search only files, ignore symlinks, folders, etc.
   - `grep -H WORD {}`: grep file for WORD. `-H` forces `grep` to print the filename.

The output of any of the commands above looks like this:

```
filename: matched line
```

for example, when searching for 'GNU':

```
/usr/local/share/doc/p7zip/DOCS/readme.txt:7-Zip is free software distributed under the GNU LGPL 
/usr/local/share/doc/p7zip/DOCS/readme.txt:1) You can compile and use compiled files under GNU LGPL rules, since 
/usr/local/share/doc/p7zip/DOCS/readme.txt:  copying.txt    - GNU LGPL license
/usr/local/share/doc/xz/history.txt:    Alexandre Sauvé helped converting the build system to use GNU
```

If you want to do a case insensitive search, replace `grep` with `grep -i` above.

Comment: re #1- I'm not sure what needs editing in that file.  I run the find command and orginally the file didn't exist, then I ran as administrative user and got the error `locate: locate database header corrupt, bigram char outside 0, 32-127: -1`

Comment: You don't need to edit `/usr/libexec/locate.updatedb`, it is more of a comment for expert users than something you must do. As I write, this applies to OS X 10.8, you may have another version. The error you mention: `locate: locate database header corrupt` says that the locate database is corrupt. Recreate it as explained in the answer doing: `sudo /usr/libexec/locate.updatedb`. You may want to delete the database first: `sudo rm /var/db/locate.database`. If you have trouble with answer #1, try another, that's why I describe 3 commands :-)

Comment: Did you manage to create the locate database? I've noticed that the `locate` command was wrong. I corrected it. Could you try it and report back?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the program [EasyFind](http://www.devontechnologies.com/products/freeware.html). It can search inside files and has a nice GUI.